# How 「何と言えばいいのかわからない」 works

Tags: meaning, parsing

I'm having a bad time with this expression:

> 何と言えばいいのかわからない

I kind of know what it means after a long time spent searching on the Internet, but I just can't grasp how this expression works on a grammar point of view.

Why the conditional?
Does the literal translation is something around the lines of "If I say something, is it OK? I don't know..." meaning "I don't know what to say"? Or is it something like "What is something good to say? I don't know..." but if that's the case, why 言えば and not 言う?

Edit: is it something like:
言えば : if I say...
何といいのか : what is good? (If I say)
わからない: I don't know...

Even if it's correct can somebody confirm it? (Or denies)

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25615/7810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

言えばいいのか　can be translated into a part of "**I don't know what would be good to say**"

> would be good to say '=. 言えばいいのか

Difference between ENG and JPN is ENG puts conditional statement on "state" while JPN puts conditional statement on "motion".

Comment: Could you (or anyone) please elaborate on what you mean by "...conditional statement on **motion**."?

Comment: @G-Cam My guess is the answerer is trying to say the Japanese conditional always comes with verbs (motion), whereas in English if-clauses are about "states". For example, here 言えば is a conditional. I am not sure I agree with that assessment.